# Getting the width of a master shape in Visio

Tags: excel, vba, visio

I am trying to write a function in VBA that drops a master object at the bottom left corner of its selection box, to do this I need to get the width and height of the master shape, and then place it at x + width/2, y + height / 2. But I cannot figure out how to access the width and height properties of the master shape. I noticed that there is the PageSheet property of a master, but the documentation doesn't say anything about how to access the cells within that sheet.

I have a stencil variable where I am accessing a particular master by name, and I don't know how to get the master width or height before dropping it via Page.Drop.

This line doesn't work.

```
PlumbingStencil.Masters(AntennaMasterName).PageSheet.Cells ("width")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the BoundingBox method on the master object. This will give you the extent of the master, which will let you calculate the width.